# How do you keep user logged in using by storing tokens in localstorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am following this tutorial to implement authentication:
https://medium.com/technest/implement-user-auth-in-a-django-react-app-with-knox-fc56cdc9211c

When the user goes to my app's base url, it redirects them to a login page if they are not authenticated. This is what my app.js looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path='/feed' component={Feed} />
            <Route exact path='/register' component={RegisterForm} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginForm} />
            
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My PrivateRoute.js:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      if (auth.isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      } else if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />;
      } else {
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }
    }}
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Here, the authentication works fine, and correctly links to my Dashboard.js component. Within my Dashboard.js, I am just rendering another component I have, called Profile.js, which displays users' profiles.

In the first code I showed (App.js), outside of the  tags, I have my Sidebar.js component that is always rendered regardless of whether the user is logged in.

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
// Button event to switch to feed page.
  render() {
    const { user, isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

    return (
        <>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <a onClick={this.props.logout} id="logout_btn">
                <span className="fa fa-lock"></span></a>
            <NavLink id="profile_btn" to="/">
                <span className="fa fa-user-circle"></span></NavLink>
            <NavLink id="feed_btn" to="/feed">
                <span className="fa fa-address-book"></span></NavLink>
        </div>
        <div id="brand">
            <h1>Cook Simple</h1>
            <p id="username-goes-here"></p>
            <a id="add_btn" href="{% url 'recipe:recipe_new' %}">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> </a>
        </div>
        </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Sidebar);
```

On this sidebar, I have one button that links to the aforementioned Profile and another button that links to another component called Feed. Clicking the Profile button works fine - it goes to my base url, which goes to the PrivateRoute, sees that the user is authenticated, and renders the Profile. However, clicking the button for Feed shows that the prop 'auth' is undefined. The code for Feed:

```
class Feed extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllRecipes();
  }
  setGrid() {
    try {
      document.getElementById("grid-container-PROFILE").id = "grid-container-FEED"
      console.log("Feed Loaded")
    }
    catch {
      console.log("Feed Already Loaded")
    }
  }

  render() {
    this.setGrid()
    return (
    <>
      <div id="brand">
        <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="title-FEED" id="recipecards-FEED">
        <div id="recipecard-container-FEED">
          <RecipeList />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    all_recipes: state.all_recipes,
    auth: state.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    getAllRecipes,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Feed)
```

Within this component, I would like to be able to access auth.user to render some data within the user object. However, it appears that auth is undefined.

The actions and reducers I am using for authentication is the same as the linked tutorial.
Here are their gists:

auth actions: https://gist.github.com/kjmczk/2c287f1d615824c627580bd2a8067fcb#file-auth-js

auth reducers: https://gist.github.com/kjmczk/64f302546e4cd38ff922cf5d59192b8e#file-auth-js

Comment: do you need to show the `feed` button to the user if they're not logged in?

Comment: Not necessarily. To be more general, I cannot figure out how to keep the user logged in and still be able to access the auth state when navigating to other pages. I've gathered that one of the methods is storing one of the tokens in LocalStorage or cookies (Using Django Knox), but I don't know how that connects to being logged in. Checking local storage, I can see that tokens are being stored as intended. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You could store your token in your cookies and set your expiry date of the token to the cookie itself. Then in the app, you could say, if the cookie is present, then the user is logged in otherwise not.

Comment: I've been trying to debug with React Developer Tools and came across something interesting. I stopped trying to render the logged-in user's username to check the props of my Feed component, and it seems that the Feed component actually has all the props, including 'auth' and other recipe things. This makes me wonder when when I try to access the username using 'this.props.auth.user.username' from this component, it gives me **TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When looking at my props with React DevTools, the components seemed to all have the **auth** prop, but whenever I tried to actually use it, I got an error. I fixed this by only accessing the prop after checking that the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a syntax error.
Try replacing:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Feed);
```

With:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Feed);
```

Removing the parentheses.

Comment: Good catch. This may have fixed some some other problems but unfortunately not my authentication problem.